# Необходимо уменьшить maxlenght с 18 до 16. Где находится этот файл?

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce, wordpress-плагины

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

На странице заполнения формы заказа cheсkout (woocommerce) - нужно немного уменьшить длину поля ввода телефона с 18 до 16. Много где искал на сервере - не нашел. Собственно где найти этот файл, чтобы поправить длину ввода?

Comment: Пожалуйста, уточните вашу конкретную проблему или приведите более подробную информацию о том, что именно вам нужно. В текущем виде сложно понять, что именно вы спрашиваете.

Comment: Нигде никакие файлы искать не нужно. В кастомайзере или дочерней теме прописываешь нужные тебе стили.

Comment: /wp-content/themes/himmelen-child/functions.php - нашел здесь, если вдруг кому то интересно :)

Comment: @ИгорьБеляев это никому неинтересно. У вас дочерняя от неизвестной темы. Вероятность, что кто-то найдёт такую же дочернюю тему, равна 0.

Answer (score 0):

Вот пример для поля Название компании, экшен должен помочь

```
add_filter( 'woocommerce_checkout_fields', 'custom_checkout_fields', 9999 );
 
function custom_checkout_fields( $fields ) {
   $fields['billing']['billing_company']['maxlength'] = 16;
   return $fields;
}
```